# Should I design UI in raster or in vector editing software?

Tags: ios, gui

I am working on a IOS city builder game (more like planet builder)
but that's not the case, I was making the buttons in photoshop when something hit me:
"if I make raster icons in photoshop, they will look pixelated on ipads!"

And so I proceded to illustrator to create the same things, but illustrator has nowhere near the amount of cool tools, that made my buttons look so cool in photoshop.

The question:
Should I stick with vector graphics and make them work? so then I have resizable buttons.
or
Should I just create several sets of buttons, which are different sizes?  a set for ipads,a set for iPhone 5's a set for iPhone 6's..

Comment: Both approaches are okay really. A combination of two as well - you can design in Il and export to Ps. Pick the one that allows you to achieve your desired goal with less effort.

Comment: Thanks for reply Krom.  I have several questions regarding the development process, should I ask them all in one question, or break them up into more concrete topics, like how you did to this question's title?

Comment: This is QA site, so each question should be separate. Please read the Help Center guidelines about which questions are good and which are bad fit fir the site format. If you have generic open-ended questions, they are likely to get closed. You can contact me if you like, skype kromster80

Comment: Alright, I will send you my questions these couple of days. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

As Krom Stern pointed out, there is no "correct" way of doing UI for a game. To be honest the whole rasterVSvector thing is misleading, as you should always chose the one that works best in the particular case (look at this --> [article](http://grassovsky.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/bitmap-vs-vector/) for more info on raster/vector, and when to prefer one over the other).

Now when it comes to games two things are always in conflict, that is *memory* and *computation*. As the article above points out, **vectors might be cheaper to store but more expensive to compute**.

On the other hand, you could create a raster image of your button for the best quality (say iPad), and then generate a [mipmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) of the button (normally used for texture LoD), but this way you would have all possible button sizes, which you could swap over devices.

If you are interested in more advanced techniques for achieving resolution independent vectors, by taking advantage of the Signed Distance Field of a full scale raster image, and then re-generating it on the GPU using shaders, take a look at [this paper](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) by Valve.

That aside, I think you'll be alright if you just use bitmaps (rasters), especially if you can make them look better. **Think of optimising only if you actually need to**!

Comment: Thanks for an extensive explanation :)   bottom half of your reply contains some words and techniques that I am hardly familiar with. Is there any source of info I can jump into and find the missing pieces of knowledge?    
The problem in my case is the fact that I am the graphics person, I can do modeling, sculpting, animation, texturing, some FX. But I have a very shallow understanding of how it all integrates with code in the game engine. That is my weakness, while I have a friend who will be doing the code for the game, it feels like I am trying my luck choosing certain paths in design.

Comment: examples would be things like: how heavy is the game allowed to be(disk space)? how much of the game's storage space should the UI elements take? how certain ways of doing UI affect performance?
those and some other things are the cornerstones of understanding relating to what I should and should not do, and currently it feels like only an extensive conversation with a game developer can help me lol.

I am sorry for taking so much space, my lack of knowledge is killing me.

Comment: In that case, as I said, I would stick with simple raster UI (whatever you find more intuitive), and don't worry too much about performance now. Only start optimising after you hit an actual problem with performance (due to the UI). The easiest type of GUI is Spite-sheet style / or even single texture (Doom menu) with a smaller texture on top, which is translated so that it corresponds to the user choice (from the static menu texture underneath). That is for a menu... 
Now if you want to learn more about the mentioned things I suggest just googling the terms 1-by-1 and reading more :)